# Using CountDownLatch and ExecutorService classes to insert 100K records in DB

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to insert some values in DB from an ArrayList having more than 100K records. I am using CountDownLatch and ExecutorService classes as given below to run 10 threads at a time to improve performance while insertion. I am calling a Stored procedure to insert the Employee details into 2 different tables after some processing of details. Is it correct approach for my requirement ?

```
 public static void writeData(List<Employee> empList) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "oracle");

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(empList.size());
        ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        final CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{Call Prc_Insert_Employee(?,?,?)}");

        for (int i = 0; i < empList.size(); i++) {
            final Employee emp = empList.get(i);

            Thread worker = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        cstmt.setString(1, emp.getId());
                        cstmt.setString(2, emp.getName());
                        cstmt.setString(2, emp.getAge());
                        cstmt.executeUpdate();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally{
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                }
            };
            taskExecutor.execute(worker);
        }
        taskExecutor.shutdown();
        latch.await();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the remarks that I have regarding your code:

1. You should consider using `addBatch()` instead of `executeUpdate()` to reduce the total amount of round trips between your database and your application, it should already help a lot in term of performance especially with a remote database, maybe you won't even need to use several threads anymore with this approach.
2. I don't believe that it is a good practice to share your `CallableStatement`. I don't think that it is meant to be thread safe, you should use a dedicated `Connection` and `CallableStatement` for each thread.
3. You need to call `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` to disable the auto commit mode which is not meant to be use to load a lot of data. It means that you will need to explicitly call `connection.commit()` every x stored records.
4. In your code you are supposed to use `Runnable` instead of `Thread` as it is what is expected by the `ExecutorService`. Creating Thread instances here is not needed as it will be seen by the `ExecutorService` as `Runnable` such that you will only have 10 threads even if you provide more than 10 `Runnable` objects  to the `ExecutorService` to `execute`.
5. The CountDownLatch is not needed as it is covered already by the method shutdown() as it is mentioned into the javadoc:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

Comment: Actually, i am calling a stored procedure in my code to insert Employee details into 2 different tables after processing the records. I have edited my post with actual code.

Comment: My bad, a CallableStatement is a PreparedStatement so you can still call addBatch instead of executeUpdate, but I must admit that I never tried with stored procedure so you should still try.

Comment: @user3244519 Is my answer clear enough? Does it help you?